# Precision differences

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

I run this sum and get the symbolic answer below :

```
Sum[ (1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2), {k, 2, Infinity}]
```

> $2 - \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

I look up the sequence on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A152416) and find these digits:

```
RealDigits[ N[ 2 - Pi^2/6, 105]]
```

> {{**3, 5, 5, 0, 6, 5, 9, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 8,
>      4, 8, 3**, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 7, 4, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 8, 
>     7, 9, 3, 2, 0, 1, 5, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 1, 7, 7, 0, 6, 2, 9, 9, 9,
>      2, 5, 2, 9, 5, 9, 6, 7, 9, 9, 1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 6, 3, 7, 1, 0, 9, 9, 
>     3, 8, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 9, 5, 9, 9, 5}, 0}

When I try to replicate those digits, I get some differences at the 27th digit.

```
RealDigits[ NSum[ (1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2), {k, 2, Infinity},
WorkingPrecision -> 105]]
```

> {{**3, 5, 5, 0, 6, 5, 9, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7, 5, 8,
>      4, 8, 3**, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5, 8, 4, 4, 8, 1, 8, 6, 0, 5, 0, 6, 9, 8, 9, 
>     7, 9, 3, 3, 4, 8, 2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 2, 9, 8, 8, 0, 8, 5, 6, 2, 7, 0, 3,
>      0, 0, 8, 1, 8, 8, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 3, 7, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 9, 
>     3, 1, 3, 7, 3, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 5}, 0}

So, which is correct ?  The symbolic sum or the NSum?

**Edit** I tried with a plus between the two sums, which returns `Zeta[2]` and I get the same variances starting at the $28$-th digit.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi, thanks for that effort. I think I have a bug. I'm in v.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One needn't wrap a number in `N` since we can get the same with `RealDigits`, e.g. :

```
RealDigits[ N[ 2 - Pi^2/6, 105]] == RealDigits[ 2 - Pi^2/6, 10, 105]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

While you can find the sum of the series symbolically with `Sum` which is assumed to yield exact expressions there is no reason to work numerically with `NSum` especially when very accurate results are needed. Having said that, one encounters this issue :  **Why do I get different results with `Sum` and `NSum` ?**

The answer to this question takes into account playing with several options of numerical functions. Taking a look at the default settings of `NSum` :

```
Options[ NSum]
```

> ```
> { AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, Compiled -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None,
>   Method -> Automatic, NSumTerms -> 15, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic,
>   VerifyConvergence -> True, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision }
> ```

we conclude that it works with  a certain number of explicit terms (`15` by default) and then it estimates the contribution of the remaining  ones to the final result. One way of improving the accuracy of the result is to increase `NSumTerms` and setting appropriately `WorkingPrecission` etc. For various series appropriate settings may be different and one should play around a bit to find the optimal settings, however if we need e.g. `100` exact digits of the final result we should work with similar accuracy. To find  `105` identical digits we had to set `WorkingPrecision -> 210`, `AccuracyGoal -> 105` and increase `NSumTerms  -> 15000` :

```
RealDigits[ NSum[ 1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2, {k, 2, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 210, 
                                          AccuracyGoal -> 105, NSumTerms -> 15000], 
            10, 105] ==
RealDigits[ 2 - Pi^2/6, 10, 105]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

To sum up we should  rely on `Sum` as far as we need exact results, since it is a very powerful function and it works well in a symbolic regime, nevertheless its range is more restricted than that of `NSum`, compare e.g. :

```
NSum[ 1/(k^3 + k^5 + k^7 + k^11), {k, Infinity}]  
Sum[ 1/(k^3 + k^5 + k^7 + k^11), {k, Infinity}]
```

Even though one can get the exact sum, it takes much more time to evaluate and there are still many more series which cannot be summed up with `Sum`, while they are well estimated with `NSum` e.g.

```
NSum[ Sqrt[k]/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}]
Sum[ Sqrt[k]/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
>  2.10176
> ```

[image]

Comment: +1, because I replaced the constant one with a sum that converges to one, this might be a pathelogical example.  The pronic numbers may converge to one at a different rate than zeta[2] converges.

Comment: @FredKline In these both cases `NSum` cannot very accurately estimate the results. You should better use `Sum` wherever it would be possible. Which one does converge to `Zeta[2]` ?

Comment: The second one---1/k^2 (but starting with k=1).

Comment: I misunderstood. Change the $-$ between the two terms to a $+$ to get `zeta[2]`.

Comment: @FredKline Just evaluate this `Sum[1/k^2, {k, Infinity}] - Zeta[2]` to understand what I mean.

Comment: `Sum[(1/k^2 + 1/(k^2 - k)), {k, 2, Infinity}] - Zeta[2]` Here I changed the minus to a plus.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the sum :

```
partialSum = Sum[(1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2), {k, 2, n}]
(* (-6 - 6 n + 12 n^2 - n^2 \[Pi]^2 + 6 n^2 PolyGamma[1, n])/(6 n^2) *)
```

and

```
Limit[partialSum, n -> Infinity]
(* 2 - \[Pi]^2/6 *)
```

What you find checks :

```
a = Sum[(1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2), {k, 2, Infinity}];
b = NSum[(1/(k^2 - k) - 1/k^2), {k, 2, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 500,       
     AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 500];

a-b
(* 1.2... x 10^-27 *)
```

Copy/paste from the [link](http://oeis.org/A152416) provided ;

```
oeis = {{3, 5, 5, 0, 6, 5, 9, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1, 7, 7, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 2, 
7, 5, 8, 4, 8, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 9, 7, 4, 8, 1, 0, 7, 8, 1, 0, 5, 0, 
0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 0, 1, 5, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4, 1, 7, 7, 0, 6, 
2, 9, 9, 9, 2, 5, 2, 9, 5, 9, 6, 7, 9, 9, 1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 6, 3, 7, 
1, 0, 9, 9, 3, 8, 0, 2, 4, 1, 2, 9, 4, 6, 9, 5, 9, 9, 5}, 0};

a - FromDigits[oeis] // N
(* 2.22045*10^-16 *)

b - FromDigits[oeis] // N
(* -1.20039*10^-27 *)
```

Comment: +1, Does this mean that the limit is the correct value and if I want to compare the digits I should use the symbolic value?

Comment: That's my conclusion so far but let's wait for the experts.

Comment: o.O Odd discrepancy with such high options for `NSum`

Comment: With `NSumTerms -> 50000` the error is about `10^-125` but it prints a `NIntegrate::ncvb` error message

Comment: If you check the link provided by Nasser M. Abassi just below the OP, you will find he got exact values using Maple16.

Comment: And if you use `NSum` with additional options `Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"` and `Method -> "EulerMaclaurin", NSumTerms -> 50` the result seems to confirm the one from `Sum`.