# Can you recommend an efficient method for finding the least integer satisfying my inequality?

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

I tried find the minimum make

$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{3
   +\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}>15$

Following code is so slow when I use condition

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, NSum[1.0/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, #}] < 15 &]

Catch@Fold[If[#1 > 15, Throw@#2, #1 + 1.0/(#2 + Sqrt[#2])] &, 0.0, 
   Range[10^7]] // Timing
```

but these two are fast without condition

```
NSum[1.0/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, 10^7}]

Fold[# + 1/(#2 + Sqrt[#2]) &, 0.0, Range[10^7]]
```

How can I improve my code make it efficiency if dont't use compilation?

## Update:

Use Bisection_method

```
num = 15;
f[x_] := NSum[1/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, x}];
n = NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, f[10^#] < num &]
min = 10^(n - 1);
max = 10^n;
mid = Round[(min + max)/2];
While[Abs[f[mid] - num] > 10^-6, 
  If[f[mid] >= num, max = mid - 1];
  If[f[mid] <= num, min = mid + 1];
  mid = Round[(min + max)/2];
];
{min, mid, max}
Clear["`*"]
```

Comment: I think you should avoid `NSum` as you're wasting time calculating sums you already have. Is it acceptable to identify a range, say 9x10^6 through 10^7, then do `data = NestList[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] + 
      1./(#[[1]] + 1 + Sqrt[#[[1]] + 1])} &, {9 10^6, 
    NSum[1.0/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, 900000}] - 15}, 10^6];` ? This is very fast and you can then inspect `data`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks One canot avoid `NSum`. Read e.g. my comment to Mr.Wizard's answer. Of course there can be alwas some improvements, nevertheless in general, you can't substitute  `NSum` with anything else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it might be a good example for `FindMinimum` with the `"PrincipalAxis"` method.

First define the summation function `myfunc`:

```
Clear[myfunc]
myfunc[n_?NumericQ] := NSum[1/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, n // Round}]
myfunc[n_?(# <= 0 &)] := 0
```

then the original problem can be solved by minimizing `Abs[myfunc[n]-15]`:

```
sol = FindMinimum[Abs[myfunc[n] - 15], {n, 1}, 
  Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

> ```
> {3.92725*10^-8, {n -> 9.88133*10^6}}
> ```

```
res = n /. sol[[2]] // Round
```

> ```
> 9881329
> ```

```
FullForm[myfunc[res + #]] & /@ {-1, 0, 1}
```

> ```
> {14.999999859558717`,14.999999960727488`,15.000000061896255`}
> ```

So $res + 1 = 9881330$ is the minimal value for $n$ which makes the inequality true.

### Edit:

As @Artes suggested in the comments and in his expansive answer, when $n$ gets bigger, higher precision and accuracy are needed for achieving a correct answer, which leads to the options `NSumTerms`, `AccuracyGoal` and `WorkingPrecision` for `NSum`.

*e.g.* for $n=25$, a `myfunc` with more `NSumTerms` will be necessary:

```
Clear[myfunc]
myfunc[n_?NumericQ] := NSum[1/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, n // Round},
                            NSumTerms -> 400 ]
myfunc[n_?Positive] := 0

n /. FindMinimum[Abs[myfunc[n] - 25], {n, 1},
    Method -> "PrincipalAxis"][[2]] // Round
```

> ```
> 217788341982
> ```

Comment: I believe you can replace the entire definition of `myfunc` with `myfunc[n_?Positive] := NSum[1/(i + Sqrt[i]), {i, Round @ n}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes you're right. I nearly totally forgot `Positive`!

Comment: @Artes hmm let me have a think.. The key point of adopting `"PrincipalAxis"` is to use the built-in root-searching routine for automatic "trial and error". I'm thinking of defining a proper custom merit function so it can compute fast and precision, but I'm currently in travel and don't have access to an MMA..

Comment: @Silvia I mean that in order to have more reliable results one has to use options in `NSum` like `AccuracyGoal`, `NSumTerms` etc. Here you should include e.g. possible options of the function `myfunc`.

Comment: @Artes I see. I was thinking those options will remarkably increase the evaluation time before. Thanks for your reminding and please see my edit.

Comment: @Silvia I like `FindMinimum[..., Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]`, This seems to work well for $n(25)$. Nevertheless I'm not pleased with it e.g. for $n(30)$. Neither my method is straightforward, but seems to be indispensable  for finding the exact value which I found to be `32322783001133`. I would like someone to ask a question like this to find an automatic method for any $n(k)$ for e.g. $k \leq 1000$. That would be a really good question. Even this one is nice. I don't think any of the present answers are complete. Nonetheless +1.

Comment: @Artes Thanks. I agree with you that none of the present answers are complete. But a similar question with $n\sim 1000$ would, in my opinion, be a bit nontrivial for automatic methods. (In fact I'd expect to see it in site like [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/).) In general it looks like an interesting problem.

Comment: @Silvia Since the OP is pleased with the answers, discussing reliable automatic methods for $k \leq 1000$ would be an overkill. Nonetheless I like more challenging questions even though e.g. I still haven't accepted answers to my questions http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes?tab=questions

Comment: @Artes Hmm.. They are really challenging, and interesting. You got my +1s :)

Comment: @Silvia Thanks, complete answers  would deserve a bounty.

Answer (score 7):

One shouldn't expect a general method which might be comparable to `NSum`, which is universal on one side and very fast on the other side (`Options[ NSum, Compiled]` gives `{Compiled -> Automatic}`). Other methods can be faster only for very specific series or special data. `NSum` yields estimated results but we can alwas make them arbitrarily precise. There are adequate tools in numerical functionality like e.g. `AccuracyGoal` to reach appropriate accuracy. See this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/precision-differences/17051#17051) for a more detailed discussion related to the main issue. It appears that Silvia's and Mr.Wizard's methods seem to be more handy for this specific problem, but if you try e.g. finding the minimal `n` which satisfies 
$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}>30$ then you'll have to work with appropriately increased `WorkingPrecision` (the default value `Options[NSum, WorkingPrecision]` is `MachinePrecision`, i.e. its numerical value `$MachinePrecision` is `15.9546`). `Accumulate` wouldn't be a good approach since you'd have to sum up roughly `5 10^13` terms.

This series is obviously not convergent :

```
SumConvergence[ 1/(k + Sqrt[k]), k]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

i.e. you might explore analogical issue for any positive number not just (`15` or `30`).

To find `n` for the sum `> 15` we can try a few parameters, first we check `NSum[1/(k + Sqrt[k]), {k, 10^7}]` then we slightly decrease the upper limmit of summation and we end up with very accurate result :

```
FindRoot[ 15 - NSum[1/(k + Sqrt[k]), {k, x},
              WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 25, NSumTerms -> 10^3],
         {x, 9881300, 9881500}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 10] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {x -> 9.8813293871411276453*10^6}
> ```

Thus we have a candidate `n0 == 9881329`. Let's increase `NSumTerms` decreasing `WorkingPrecission` :

```
NSum[ 1/(k + Sqrt[k]), {k, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> 15,
      NSumTerms -> 10^5] & /@ {9881329, 9881330}
```

> ```
> {14.9999999608590703242577, 15.0000000620278381114430}
> ```

One might ensure that `n == 9881330` increasing as well `NSumTerms` up to `10^7`.

If we apply directly Silvia's method `myfunc` to determine the minimal `n` such that the sum is `> 25`we find that `n == 217788342012` which is incorrect. Mr.Wizard's methods are even worse here. Therefore we can proceed analogically as before by trial and error. It brings us to this conclusion :

```
NSum[ 1/(k + Sqrt[k]), {k, #}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 25, 
      NSumTerms -> 10^5] & /@ {217788341981, 217788341982}
```

> ```
>  {24.99999999999638162229253940380424, 25.00000000000097322645325278931633}
> ```

Thus we've found `n[25] == 217788341982.`

Answer (score 5):

Working within the loop method you could do this:

```
NestWhile[
  # + 1.0/(++i + Sqrt[i]) &,
  i = 0,
  # < 9 &
] // Timing // First

i
```

> ```
> 0.219
>
> 24197
> ```

This is reasonably fast and open-ended, but it still doesn't get you to `# < 15` very well.
Timing and result for 15:  `{106.424, 9881330}`

### Accumulate

Faster but not open-ended is to pick an arbitrary maximum and use `Accumulate`:

*EDIT: My original use of `LengthWhile` was horribly inefficient.  Much faster:*

```
1 + Tr @ UnitStep[15 - Accumulate @ Array[1.0/(# + Sqrt[#]) &, 12000000]] // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.983, 9881330}
> ```

I would favor an intelligent sampling method as shown by Artes and Silvia over either of these in most cases.

Comment: `Count[Accumulate@Array[1.0/(# + Sqrt[#]) &, 12000000], 
   x_ /; x < 15] + 1 // Timing` more faster.

Comment: @chyanog I didn't realize `LengthWhile` was taking so long.  I think we can do even better than `Count`.  Update soon.

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: @chyanog Update complete.

Comment: Very good! I'm not familiar with this function yet.

Comment: @chyanog `Accumulate` is an elegant and fast method here. But You can't work with it for significantly bigger numbers with it. There is no other than working with `NSum` and adjusting  `WorkingPrecision` and `AccuracyGoal` if you to explore this series extensively. E.g. When you want to find minimal `n` such that $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}>\;30$

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this helps re speed, but one can get an underestimated approximation byu using, say, 10^5 terms, then truncating denominators of the rest so as to get the Harmonic series values.

```
Timing[
 nstart = Ceiling[
   n /. FindRoot[
     HarmonicNumber[n] == 
      15 + HarmonicNumber[100000.] - 
       Sum[1/(k + Sqrt[N@k]), {k, 100000}], {n, 1000}]]]

(* Out[1]= {0.015600, 9825379} *)

Timing[startsum = Fold[# + 1./(#2 + Sqrt[N@#2]) &, 0.0, Range[nstart]]]

(* Out[2]= {2.574016, 14.9943234847116} *)

Timing[j = nstart + 1; 
 While[(startsum += 1./(j + Sqrt[N@j])) <= 15, j++]; j]

(* Out[4]= {0.483603, 9881330} *)
```