# Cannot Get Numerical Results to Match

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I try this numerical summation (in two parts)

```
a = NSum[(HarmonicNumber[2 m])/m^3, {m, 1, Infinity}, 
      WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 100];
N[Pi^3/24 Log[2]^2 + Log[2] Pi/16 Zeta[3] - Pi^5/960 - Pi/16 a, 100]
```

and this numerical integration

```
NIntegrate[x^2 Log[Sin[x]] Log[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 100]
```

which are supposed to give the same result, and they do, but only to 25 places.

Obviously, at least one of the results is off. How can I increase the precision so that these agree past 25 places? If that can't be done, which of these is the more accurate?

If I try to evaluate the first quantity symbolically, I get

```
b = Sum[(HarmonicNumber[2 m])/m^3, {m, 1, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> 1/144 (π^4 + 72 (EulerGamma + Log[4]) Zeta[3] - 36 Sqrt[π]  
>     (HypergeometricPFQRegularized^({0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, 0))[
>       {1, 1, 1,1, 3/2}, {2, 2, 2, 3/2}, 1])
> ```

However, `N[b,20]` never returns. The problem seems to be the evaluation of the derivative of `HypergeometricPFQRegularized`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the result of `NSum` more precise you can use  also the `NSumTerms` option  (15 by default, see e.g. [Numerical Evaluation of Sums and Products](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalEvaluationOfSumsAndProducts.html)) appropriately increased. 
Let's try e.g. :

```
a1 = NSum[ HarmonicNumber[2 m]/m^3, {m, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 140, 
             PrecisionGoal -> 70, NSumTerms -> 2000]
```

> ```
>  1.9746275368413284954203787248027995910222173561519748313727983181550691548
> ```

now compare

```
NIntegrate[ x^2 Log[Sin[x]] Log[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 75, 
                                                       PrecisionGoal -> 70 ]
N[ Pi^3/24 Log[2]^2 + Log[2] Pi/16 Zeta[3] - Pi^5/960 - Pi/16 a1, 75]

% - %%
```

> ```
>  0.0778219793722938643380943991911599389199168078241333818284167516820632583615
>  0.07782197937229386433809439919115993891991680782413338182841675168206325836
>
>  0.*10^-75
> ```

That's pretty close.

Regarding your definition of `b` I had no problems with evaluating it, e.g.

```
N[b, 70]
```

> ```
> 1.974627536841328495420378724802799591022217356151974831372798318155069
> ```

You can see that the `NSum` result is really close to this value.

For some closely related problems with `NSum` see e.g. this question [Precision differences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/precision-differences).

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew there was some option that I hadn't found that I needed to set. I've had this problem before and I am glad to know how to fix it. As for the problem evaluating the derivative of HypergeometricPFQRegularized, it might be my version, which is 8.0.1.0.

Comment: @robjohn I'm glad I could help. I had no problem in ver. 9.0.1 with `N[b, 70]`, but trying to evaluate it in `8.0.4` it`s just taken a few minutes and I still have got no result. I'll look later if one can do it successfully in `ver. 8`. I think you could try some methods in `Sum` to work around this issue.

Comment: @Artes: I will look at options in Sum to see what I can do. I tried simply evaluating the derivative of `HypergeometricPFQRegularized` by itself at the given point, and have left it running for over 30 minutes with no response. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Artes: I have acknowledged your assistance in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/331222).

Comment: This question seems like it is a duplicate of [the question you linked to.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/precision-differences)  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Clearly we encounter the same issue here and to provide a higher precision we use the same option. On the other hand I haven't marked it as an exact duplicate since there is some kind of bug in `ver.8` not present in `ver.9`, see comments above. I'll have to take a closer look if it can be explained to a larger extent and then I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, one should also remember that the `Method` options of `NSum[]` accept sub-options as well. For instance,

```
NSum[HarmonicNumber[2 m]/m^3, {m, 1, Infinity}, 
     Method -> {"EulerMaclaurin", "ExtraTerms" -> 50, 
                Method -> {NIntegrate, Method -> "DoubleExponential"}}, 
     NSumTerms -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 90, VerifyConvergence -> False, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 120]
   1.9746275368413284954203787248027995910222173561519748313727983181550691
```

In particular, when using the Euler-Maclaurin method, I have found it helpful to use the double exponential quadrature scheme of Takahasi and Mori for evaluating the needed (often improper) integrals; I have thus done so here.