# Strange NSum behavior

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation

If I do:

```
 NSum[(i + 1)/(i + 2) LegendreP[i, 0] LegendreP[i, 0], {i, 0, Infinity}]
```

I get:

```
1.25216
```

If I do:

```
Sum[(i + 1)/(i + 2) LegendreP[i, 0] LegendreP[i, 0], {i, 0, 1000}] // N
```

The result is:

```
2.40862
```

This last result is larger than the infinite sum, but the sum terms are all nonnegative. That is not possible. Am I wrong or is *Mathematica* wrong?

Comment: The odd terms are zero.

Comment: One thing is that I am not sure if the sum diverges. If this is the case, the infinity sum is wrong anyway.

Comment: The sum diverges.

Comment: But see here `SumConvergence[(i + 1)/(i + 2) LegendreP[i, 0] LegendreP[i, 0], i, 
 Assumptions -> Element[i, Integers] && Mod[i, 2] == 0]`!

Comment: Interesting. I did an Integral test and it diverged.

Comment: This post is closely related: [Cannot Get Numerical Results to Match](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/cannot-get-numerical-results-to-match/21452#21452), namely you should try e.g. `NSum[(i + 1)/(i + 2) LegendreP[i, 0] LegendreP[i, 0], {i, 0, 
  Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 1000]`.  Similar issue is discussed also here [Precision differences](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/precision-differences/17051#17051)

Comment: @Artes This gives probably wrong result as you can cross check `exp = Sum[(i + 1)/(i + 2) LegendreP[i, 0] LegendreP[i, 0], {i, 0, k}];
exp /. k -> 30000 // N` with the result your code gives!

Comment: which of them is correct result is a question itself..

Answer (score 1):

We have the known result (see e.g. Abramowitz and Stegun)

$$P_{2n}(0)=\left(-\frac14\right)^n\binom{2n}{n}$$

Substituting this result into your sum (while also exploiting the oddness of the odd-order Legendre polynomials) yields

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}\binom{2k}{k}^2\left(\frac1{16}\right)^k$$

which *Mathematica* says is divergent, and that is certainly because the central binomial coefficients grow quite quickly ($\binom{2k}{k}\sim\frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$).

Nevertheless, we can ask *Mathematica* to evaluate the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}\binom{2k}{k}^2 z^k$$

```
Sum[(((2 k + 1) Binomial[2 k, k]^2)/(2 k + 2)) x^k, {k, 0, ∞}] // FullSimplify
   (EllipticK[16 x] - EllipticE[16 x])/(8 π x)
```

where we have obtained a result in terms of complete elliptic integrals.

Unfortunately, it is also known that $K(m)$ exhibits a logarithmic singularity  at $m=1$, so we again reach the conclusion that the original sum is indeed divergent.