# Sum and NSum gives different solutions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I'm working on a *Mathematica*  lab for Calc. 2, and I ran into a problem last night. I was trying to calculate the midpoint approximation of the definite integral of `Cos[x]` from 0 to 2. Here's what I came up with:

```
Clear[a, b, n, f] 

f[x_] = Cos[x]

a := 0; b := 2; n := 578

N[((b - a)/n)*Sum[f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}]]

0.909298
```

This is fine, but if I try to use `NSum` instead of `N[...Sum[...]]` then this happens:

```
Clear[a, b, n]

a := 0; b := 2; n := 578

((b - a)/n)*NSum[f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}]
```

> During evaluation of In[35]:= SequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[35]:= SequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect. >>
>
> 35.538

According to the documentation, `Sum` evaluates the given sum (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html), and the `N` function gives the numerical value of the parameter (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html). Also, `NSum` should give the numerical approximation of the sum. To my understanding, `N[Sum[...]]` Should be the same as `NSum[...]`, or am I missing something?

It's not a huge deal as far as typing more, but I'd just like to know why it doesn't work as expected. I've read online that `NSum` apparently tries to work out part of the sum symbolically, but even if it does I don't see how it could be *THAT* much different from the real answer.

Comment: Its probably roundoff errors... `((b - a)/n)*Sum[f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}] // N` works.

Comment: Yes, that does work. That's the same as the first code block that I posted above, but I just don't understand how they could be that much different. The second block above seems to work where `n < 159` . Once n gets any bigger you get those warnings and the values get sporadic.

Comment: ok then this works: `((b - a)/n)*
 NSum[f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}, NSumTerms -> 1000]`

Comment: You're missing the fact that `N[Sum[...]]` computes the sum *exactly* and then converts it to floating point output, whereas `NSum[...]` attempts, through various numerical mechanisms, to *approximate* the sum (and might not even actually calculate all the terms in the sum in doing so). As the help notes, it can be fooled and needs judicious application of appropriate options to work well. It sounds like you are attempting to use `NSum[...]` where you really want something like `Total@N@Table[...]`, especially if you're experimenting with Riemann integration.

Comment: as @whuber said, you probably want to use `Total@Table[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll look into Total@Table. I've only been using Mathematica since I started Calculus last semester, so I don't know all the ins and outs thoroughly, yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crucial point is that `N@Sum` is not `NSum`.

### What `N@Sum` is

`N@Sum` will first try to evaluate the sum symbolically and then approximate it numerically. Only if `Sum` cannot perform the first task, and then returns (at least partially) unevaluated, `N` will resort to using `NSum`.
In case of a *finite* sum, `Sum` will always return an evaluated result, consisting possibly of a sum (`Plus`) of all the terms.

In this example you can see the first situation described: the sum is simplified to `\[Pi]^2/6` and then `N` approximates it:

```
N@Sum[1/n^2, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] // Trace
```

In the following example instead, `Sum` is not able to find an explicit formula, and in the trace you can see that `N` is called with the unchanged sum as the argument:

```
N@Sum[Log[n]/(1 + n^2), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] // Trace
```

You can even check that `NSum` is called by blocking it (I thank L. B. Shifrin for the inspiration):

```
Block[{NSum}, 
  Hold@Evaluate@N@Sum[Log[n]/(1 + n^2), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
]
```

### What `NSum` is

As the *Documentation Center* clearly states, `NSum` tries to approximate the result by various summation methods (listed under *More Information*).

The guide also states that:

> You should realize that with sufficiently pathological summands, the algorithms used by `NSum` can give wrong answers. In most cases, you can test the answer by looking at its sensitivity to changes in the setting of options for `NSum`.

To get a better sense of this distinction, I think it's useful to check the evaluation

### Experimenting

This code shows you at which points `f` is called:

```
f[x_] := (Sow[x, "f"]; Cos[x])
a = 0; b = 2; n = 578;
Reap[NSum[f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n},
          EvaluationMonitor :> (Sow[i, "i"])],
     {"f", "i"}][[2]];
Print["f[] has been called at: ", %[[1, 1]]]
ListPlot[%%[[2, 1]], PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "Evaluation points"]
```

As you can see, `f` has been called 8 times and `NSum` performed 39 evaluation cycles. This clearly indicates that not all 578 points have been taken in consideration.

On the other hand, if you write

```
f[x_] := (Sow[x, "f"]; Cos[x])
a = 0; b = 2; n = 578;
Reap[Sum[N@f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}], "f"][[2, 1]] // Short
% // Length
```

you can see that a long list of exactly 578 evaluation is generated.

### Conclusion

What you really need to do is

```
Sum[N@f[a + (i - (1/2))*((b - a)/n)], {i, 1, n}]
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Great, detailed answer.

Comment: @Caleb1994 This question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/precision-differences is closely related to your problem.

Comment: Very nice analysis! (+1)

Comment: @whuber One should however be careful not to overstate the differences between `Sum` and `NSum`. According to the documentation for `Sum` (under "Properties"): **Applying `N` to an unevaluated sum effectively uses NSum**