# Integrate not restricting variable with Assumptions option?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am integrating `g` over the region:

```
RegionPlot[ 0 <= x <= 3 && 1 - x <= y < -(2/3) x + 2, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

The limits of integration are

$$\int _0^1\int _{1-x}^{2-\frac{2 x}{3}}g[x,y]dydx+\int _1^3\int _0^{2-\frac{2 x}{3}}g[x,y]dydx$$

The expected answer is obtained from evaluating these integrals.

```
g[x_, y_] := 3 x + y^2

Integrate[g[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 1 - x, -(2/3) x + 2}] + 
 Integrate[g[x, y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 0, -(2/3) x + 2}]
(* 125/12 *)
```

I then had the idea that I could use the `Assumptions` option to restrict `y` and only evaluate one `Integration`.  However, the answer is returned is the same as an unrestricted `y` integration.

```
Integrate[g[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1 - x, -(2/3) x + 2}, 
 Assumptions -> y >= 0]
(* 103/4 *)

Integrate[g[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 1 - x, -(2/3) x + 2}]
(* 103/4 *)
```

Why doesn't `Integrate` restrict `y` with the `Assumption` option?

Comment: It appears that `Assumptions` is intended only to eliminate generated conditions, not to reduce the range of an integration variable.  Thus, `Integrate[1, {y, -1, 1}]` and `Integrate[1, {y, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> y > 0]` produce the same answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another clean approach to performing a single integration builds on  the input to the plot in the question.

```
r = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 3 && 0 <= y <= 2 && 1 - x <= y < -(2/3) x + 2, {x, y}]
Integrate [3 x + y^2, {x, y} ∈ r]
(* 125/12 *)
```

Comment: This is it! (+1) I will hold out for a while before accepting. Just in case. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here you loose the control of proper integration limits and the result is different since the region of integration is different.
In general **using another variable as a limit of integration is a bad idea**  moreover **using `Assumptions` to restrict integration (or summation) variables is not reasonable**, you can find an analogous mistake in a different context here:  [Double series over primes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/double-series-over-primes/32517#32517).

If you want to get the correct result in  one integral there are many different approaches. Let's provide two the most natural and reliable, both  working in earlier versions of *Mathematica* :

```
Integrate[ g[x, y] Boole[1 - x <= y <= -(2/3) x + 2], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

> ```
> 125/12
> ```

One can use also `HeavisideTheta` appropriately, which sometimes may appear more efficient (see e.g. this post [How to plot and find the volume of a solid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/how-to-plot-and-find-the-volume-of-a-solid/39164#39164)), equivalent calculation with `HeavisideTheta`:

```
Integrate[ g[x, y] HeavisideTheta[y + x - 1] HeavisideTheta[-y - 2/3 x + 2],
           {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: The second integral is just restricting $y >= 0$ on $x ∈ [1 ,3]$. Why doesn't an `Assumption -> y >= 0` achieve this in the single `Integral` evaluation.

Comment: Apparently your understanding of `Assumptions` is incorrect, you cannot limit another variable in this way, this is a common mistake. Read e.g. the second answer (by Sektor) to this question [Double series over primes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/double-series-over-primes).  Is it clear?

Comment: @Edmund In `Assumptions` you can limit  constants, not variables of integration!

Comment: Yes. My understanding of `Assumptions` was off. Your solution works (+1) but is not the conceptual approach I am seeking.

Comment: @Edmund This had been the best approach until the version 10 of _Mathematica_ (remember my previous remarks) and in various cases it is still the best. I remember several cases when new functionality worked incorrectly, so I'm not sure `ImplicitRegion` is a perfect approach. Read this answer [Finding length of intersection of two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58768/finding-length-of-intersection-of-two-surfaces/58769#58769) paying attention to its earlier versions and comments beneath. For this reason I'm not quite convinced to `ImplicitRegion`.

Comment: Cautions and caveats noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Amplifying on the answer by @bbgodfrey

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 3 && 1 - x <= y < -(2/3) x + 2, {x, y}];
```

What you plotted was

```
RegionPlot[rgn, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 2}}]
```

[image]

However, restricting the portion of the region displayed does not change the region. The region defined by the inequalities is larger than the region that you displayed.

```
RegionPlot[rgn]
```

[image]

```
g[x_, y_] := 3 x + y^2

Integrate[g[x, y], {x, y} ∈ rgn]

(*  103/4  *)
```

Restricting the region to that corresponding to the region displayed in the original plot

```
rgn2 = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= 3 && 0 <= y <= 2 && 1 - x <= y < -(2/3) x + 2, {x, y}];

Integrate[g[x, y], {x, y} ∈ rgn2]

(*  125/12  *)
```

Comment: Yes. I think I will change to plotting the regions without bounding the variables so I don't overlook this again. (+1)